# IIS - Overuse of memory is normal?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, iis-7, iis-6, performance-tuning

I have two servers running Asp.net applications. Sometimes applications are too slow and memory usage seems exaggerated.

**Specifications:**

**SERVER #1**

**OS:** Microsoft Windows 2003 R2

**Memory:** 4GB

**Processor:** Intel Xeon L5520 2.27GHz

**Number of pools in IIS:** 108 (two sites to each pool)

**Average memory in use:** 8.91 GB (Already using pagefile memory)

**SERVER #2**

**OS:** Microsoft Windows 2008 R2

**Memory:** 8GB

**Processor:** Intel Xeon L5520 2.26GHz

**Number of pools in IIS:** 14 (two sites to each pool)

**Average memory in use:** 2.84 GB

This hardware is compatible with the demand that was allocated?

It is normal IIS using too much memory?

Its cut through the manager?

Comment: Is that 216 *websites* on one server? If so, there's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Server #1 is way overloaded for what you're tossing at it. You need to either a) add more RAM and possibly a second processor if supported, or b) get another server and move some sites around.